# Is it okay to use a modified name of a well known brand in my game?

Tags: copyright, trademark, video-games

If for example, my game has a fast food restaurant in the world, can it be called **Wc**Donald's instead of **Mc**Donald's to get around the issue of using a brand name?

I see this being done in other forms of media *(the WcDonald's one is prevalent in anime for example)* but I don't know about the legality of it in the US.

Comment: I honestly don't know how legal this is but I sure do remember racing against Nigel Mainsail in my youth.